# UIMA Ruta version 2.7.0

Tags: uima, ruta

I've upgraded the Uima Ruta version to 2.7.0. I received the following messages in the console, will it affect any process.

```
Nov 08, 2019 11:54:31 AM org.apache.uima.internal.util.XMLUtils createSaxTransformerFactory(614)
WARNING: SAXTransformerFactory didn't recognize setting attribute http://javax.xml.XMLConstants/property/accessExternalDTD
Nov 08, 2019 11:54:31 AM org.apache.uima.internal.util.XMLUtils createSaxTransformerFactory(621)
WARNING: SAXTransformerFactory didn't recognize setting attribute http://javax.xml.XMLConstants/property/accessExternalStylesheet
log4j:WARN No appenders could be found for logger (org.springframework.validation.DataBinder).
log4j:WARN Please initialize the log4j system properly.
log4j:WARN See http://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/faq.html#noconfig for more info.
Nov 08, 2019 11:54:32 AM org.apache.uima.jcas.impl.JCasImpl reportInitErrors(809)
WARNING: 
JCas Type "org.apache.uima.ruta.type.DebugBlockApply" implements getters and setters for feature "timestamp", but the type system doesnt define that feature.
JCas Type "org.apache.uima.ruta.type.DebugRuleApply" implements getters and setters for feature "timestamp", but the type system doesnt define that feature.
JCas Type "org.apache.uima.ruta.type.DebugScriptApply" implements getters and setters for feature "timestamp", but the type system doesnt define that feature.

Nov 08, 2019 11:54:32 AM org.apache.uima.jcas.impl.JCasImpl reportInitErrors(809)
WARNING: 
JCas Type "org.apache.uima.ruta.type.DebugBlockApply" implements getters and setters for feature "timestamp", but the type system doesnt define that feature.
JCas Type "org.apache.uima.ruta.type.DebugRuleApply" implements getters and setters for feature "timestamp", but the type system doesnt define that feature.
JCas Type "org.apache.uima.ruta.type.DebugScriptApply" implements getters and setters for feature "timestamp", but the type system doesnt define that feature.

Nov 08, 2019 11:54:33 AM org.apache.uima.jcas.impl.JCasImpl reportInitErrors(809)
WARNING: 
JCas Type "org.apache.uima.ruta.type.DebugBlockApply" implements getters and setters for feature "timestamp", but the type system doesnt define that feature.
JCas Type "org.apache.uima.ruta.type.DebugRuleApply" implements getters and setters for feature "timestamp", but the type system doesnt define that feature.
JCas Type "org.apache.uima.ruta.type.DebugScriptApply" implements getters and setters for feature "timestamp", but the type system doesnt define that feature.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. There was an update of the type system adding a new feature timestamp. You need to update the type systems in your project, e.g., right-click on your ruta project -> UIMA Ruta -> Update Project. Rebuild the descriptors by cleaning the project.